Integrating a custom HTML template into Mailchimp
A client wants to integrate a new template into Mailchimp. For this he sends me the designed model, and I integrate it in html format. So far so good.
Editable content areas
Once integrated, I add the tokens specific to Mailchiimp so that each block of text or each image is editable.
For example :
<tr>
  <td style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">
    <h3 mc:edit="new_heading" mc:label="H3" style="margin:0 0 10px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000">title</h3>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">
    <p mc:edit="new_copy" style="margin:0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>

In Mailchimp, I go to “template”, “create template”, and I choose “Past in code”, to copy and paste my email.
I then find it in "content", "Email template". In the preview window, when I go to "Edit Design", I can edit all the texts and images to which I added the mc:edit attributes. So far so good.
Repeating and move content area
My email template is supposed to contain all the blocks. Let's say that it contains 10 blocks. My client, depending on the campaigns, wants to use for example, first, blocks 1, 5, 8 and 9. In the next campaign, he will want to use blocks 3,4, 6 and 10.
In the current configuration I cannot delete or move anything, but simply edit the blocks.
I read everywhere that removing or moving blocks is possible, thanks to the mc:repeatable and mc:variant attributes.
<table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%" mc:repeatable="content" mc:variant="variant_1">
<tr>
  <td style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">
    <h3 mc:edit="new_heading" mc:label="H3" style="margin:0 0 10px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#000000">title</h3>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">
    <p mc:edit="new_copy" style="margin:0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    </p>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

So I add these attributes, and indeed, I have a plus and a minus, I can duplicate the blocks, and delete the new blocks created. I notice that the initial block, even if it has the plus and minus, I cannot delete it.
If I want to hide it, it says that you cannot use mc:hideable at the same time as mc:repeatable.
Despite adding the attributes, I don't have any arrows to move the blocks.
So actually I can't delete blocks, I can't hide them, and I can't move them. Is that right?
Question
So my question is the following : from a template coded in html, what are the possibilities for a client, from the model that I send them:
can he choose the blocks he wants for his campaign and delete any he doesn't want.
Move the blocks to get a different design each time?
what else I tried
I point out that I have already retrieved the code for a Mailchimp template, and I saw that it was possible to add a certain number of divs above and below each table, to add the controls which display the the drag and drop icon (to move the block), the copy paste icon and the trash can (to delete the block). But although they are displayed, they are not functional...
thank you in advance for your help, I admit that I do not understand the benefit of coding an email from scratch in Mail Chimp given the limitations imposed.
